# Installing a Gitlab Server as a HA solution

Tags: gitlab, high-availability

I'm trying to come up to a solution for my company in where we have a High Availability solution with GitLab. I know there are ways to do it if I install GitLab on AWS (I saw the documentation for it)https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/university/high-availability/aws/ , but I'm not sure if I install it with Docker on a on-site would be also another option for a HA solution. Since we have the Hardware already in the company why not using it already?

Comment: ?  All the startup methods are given here ... https://about.gitlab.com/installation/   (It seems inconceivable, these days, you would run something like this on "a server in your own office".  Just press a button and use a cloud service.)  (The obvious rare exception is for exceptionally high security situations.)

Comment: Docker actually does not propose to use it for persisted storage , you ll need to create multiple mount points , so still cant see how this will work as a solution for you.

Comment: Interesting read: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/www-gitlab-com/blob/4909fd221944994494f08f2b7364dcfdfbc292ff/source/handbook/infrastructure/production-architecture/index.html.md

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm not sure if I install it with Docker on a on-site would be also another option for a HA solution.

For Premium instances, that would be [what Geo is for](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/geo.html):

> Geo connects GitLab instances together.
> One GitLab instance is designated as a primary node and can be run with multiple secondary nodes.

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/geo/replication/img/geo_architecture.png]

And with [GitLab 14.6 (Dec. 2022)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/12/22/gitlab-14-6-released/#seamless-worldwide-performance-with-geo), still for premium instance:

> Geo secondary sites transparently proxy write requests to the primary site while accelerating most read requests.
>
> Systems administrators can provide all GitLab users across their organization with a single URL that automatically uses the Geo site closest to them.
> Users no longer need to use different configuration to benefit from Geo, or worry about what operations won’t work on Geo secondary sites.
> Globally distributed teams now benefit from accelerated `git clone` or `git pull` commands, and a seamless worldwide experience.
>
> Secondary proxying and unified URL support is enabled by default for new Geo installations. You can also [set up a unified URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/geo/secondary_proxy/index.html#set-up-a-unified-url-for-geo-sites) on an existing Geo installation and enable secondary proxying.

---

And [GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#geo-supports-buildkit-cache-images) (July 2022) adds:

> ### Geo supports BuildKit cache images
>
> With GitLab 15.2, Geo supports replication of [BuildKit cache images](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/spec.md).
>
> With the support of the BuildKit cache image format in GitLab 15.2, and the addition of support for [OCI container images](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#geo-supports-oci-container-images) in GitLab 15.1, Geo now supports a broader list of container types.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/geo/replication/docker_registry.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/365858).